# How to display an element with ng-show based on AngularJS Bootstrap UI Accordion state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've got a few dynamic accordions which based on `$resource` like so:

```
$scope.categories = $resource.query() // Written as such for simplicity sake
```

Then in my template I've got the following:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="category in categories" is-open="$first">
    <accordion-heading>
        <button ng-show="IDontKnow">...</button>
        ...
    </accordion-heading>
</accordion>
```

With the above, I get my first open by default which is what I want, however I'd like to display the button above only if the accordion is open. Because `$first` is special variable from `ng-repeat` I can't change it. I've tried to use `isOpen` like so:

```
<button ng-show="category.isOpen">...</button>
```

But that didn't work either. How can I achieve this? Please bear in mind the accordions are based on dynamic content.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/rv6esLxJuE6NLlxwhZkh?p=preview

you can use ng-init ie: `ng-init="category.isOpen=$first"`

HTML:

```
   <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

  <accordion-group ng-repeat="category in categories" is-open="category.isOpen" ng-init="category.isOpen=$first">
    <accordion-heading>
      I can have markup, too!
      <button ng-show="category.isOpen">I'm the button</button>
    </accordion-heading>
    This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Comment: The only issue is that the button is inside the accordion, but more importantly its visible per accordion. If the accordion is open, the button (inside the accordion heading panel) is visible. I've updated my code sample to illustrate it better.

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/rv6esLxJuE6NLlxwhZkh?p=preview

Comment: thanks It does work, however the first accordion is no longer opening as it was before and I can't see why to be honest. Any idea?

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK  `is-open="category.isOpen" ng-init="category.isOpen=$first"` have you seen example ? the first one is open

Comment: yes, I have, and I've copied it verbatim but there was a code in the inner accordion that was interfering with it. My bad, sorry. I've found and fixed it. Thanks again!